# Ошибка диска 0x0E

Tags: ассемблер, диск, x86-64, disk

Здраствуйте, хочу написать OS (Пожалуста не кидайте камнями). Зупускаю загрузку секторов, но всегда получаю ощибку 0x0E прерывания 13h.

```
disk_load:
    pusha
    push dx

    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, dh
    mov cl, 0x02
    xor ch, ch
    xor dh, dh

    int 13h
    jc disk_error

    pop dx
    cmp al, dh
    jne sectors_error

    popa
    ret

disk_error:
    mov al, 'D'
    mov ah, 0x0E
    xor bh, bh
    int 10h
    
    xor al, al
    mov dx, ax
    call print_hex

    jmp disk_loop ; (jmp $)
```

Что-бы я не делал вегда вывод D0x0E00 (0E  fixed disk controlled data address mark detected).

Записываю загрузчик в .img файл из запускаю через qemu.

Я уже не знаю что делать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А что у вас в DX на момент входа в disk_load ? `mov al, dh` выглядит очень странно ...

Comment: И номера диска в DL не наблюдаю что то

Comment: А еще адреса буфера, куда читать не видно...

Comment: Дык, ты забыл `ah`  старый сохранить перед вызовом `int 10h` вот у тебя `0x0E` и печатается вместо нормальной ошибки…